# binary expression of integer to boolean array

Tags: c++, binary, boolean

Given an integer, I want to get its binary expression, and save it in a boolean array.

For example,

```
bool b[32];
int a=98; // a=0b1100010
```

I hope there is a way to make b becomes 010001100000000000000000 or something similar.

I know little about bitset, but I don't know how to convert bitset to boolean array (other than using for loop).

I thought it 98 is store in computer as a sequence of 1 or 0, there should be some way that we can get that sequence out, but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with `bitset`.

To construct a `bitset` of size 32 containing 98 you can just do:

```
bitset<32> foo(98);
```

You could also construct so insert that in the most significant bits by doing:

```
bitset<32> foo(98 << 24);
cout << foo.to_string() << endl; // Prints: 01100010000000000000000000000000
```

As far as converting `bitset` to an array, there's no need you can use the `operator[]` on `bitset`. Plus you get:

- `all`
- `any`
- `count`
- `flip`
- `none`
- `reset`
- `set`
- `to_string`
- `to_ulong`
- `to_ullong`

Plus all the logical operators that are supported by integers.

**Edit:**

OK let's say you have 100 `int`s that you want to put into `bitset<sizeof(int)>`s in: `vector<int> bar;` Lets also say for the point of example that you want to reverse only the odd `int`s. Here's what I would do:

```
vector<bitset<sizeof(int) * 8>> foo(bar.size()); // Creating as many empty bitsets as there are ints in bar

for (int i = 0; i < bar.size(); ++i){
    foo[i] = bar[i]; // Initializing each element of foo

    if (foo[i][0].test()){ // Is this number odd
        for (int j = 0; j < foo[i].size() / 2; ++j){ // This loop reverses the elements in a bitset
            const bool swap = foo[i][j];

            foo[i][j] = foo[i][foo[i].size() - j - 1];
            foo[i][foo[i].size() - j - 1] = swap;
        }
    }
    cout << i << ". " << foo[i] << endl; // This is for testing purposes it'll print the contents of the indexed bitset in foo
}
```

Comment: The bit-string is _reversed_ in the OP's 32-bit example, not padded.

Comment: I need to store the binary in array because I will need it later and there is a lot of number. is there a way that can create a lot of bitset, that is, foo1, foo2, foo3, ...?

Comment: @k99731 I have three clarification questions: 1) Did you mean to reverse the bits of 98 in your original question? 2) You can create as many `bitset`s as you want, are you perhaps thinking of creating an array of them? 3) Why do you need to store as a `bool[]` why will a `bitset` not work?

Comment: 1. Yes. But i in fact want to get the binary (not necessarily reversed) of eg 100 integer.  2. how to create as many as bitset as different variable?  3. i want it in bool array since i dont know a way to create as mant bitsets as i want.

Comment: @k99731 OK I've updated the answer with some example code. In this example `foo[42]` is the 42nd `bitset` created and `foo[42][13]` is the 13th bit of the 42nd `bitset` created.